# Is there a way to batch edit all private photos on Flickr?

Tags: flickr

I'd like to add tags to all private photos on my Flickr account. Is there a way to do this in the Organizr or using a 3rd-party application like h4ppierphotos?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from [Organizr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/organize/)

- Click on "More options" next to the Search button. Select "Only show private content" from the dropdown.

[image]

- Select all photos, drag them to the centre & then click on "Add Tags" & add the relevant tags

[image]